# using GameScene as a parameter for passing it to a different class - Swift2

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to have all the setup functions in a separate class called Setup, like this:

```
class Setup {
    var scene: GameScene!

    init(scene: GameScene){
        self.scene = scene
    }

    func setupBackground(bg1: SKSpriteNode, bg2: SKSpriteNode) {
        bg1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        bg1.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        bg1.size = CGSize(width: scene.size.width, height: scene.size.height)
        scene.addChild(bg1)

        bg2.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        bg2.position = CGPointMake(0, bg1.size.height + 1)
        bg2.size = CGSize(width: scene.size.width, height: scene.size.height)
        scene.addChild(bg2)
    }
}
```

And then calling it in GameScene like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var bg1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "lightSky")
    var bg2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "lightSky")
    var setup = Setup(self)

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.size = view.bounds.size
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -1.0)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        setup.setupBackground(bg1, bg2: bg2)
    }
}
```

But am getting an error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Setup' with an argument list of type '(NSObject -> () -> GameScene)'

So I am guessing the type of scene parameter is wrong but don't know which one is right then.

Comment: Where do you create the `setup` variable in `GameScene`? Please show how it's initialized.

Comment: It works now, thanks to you :) The thing was that I was calling self for GameScene directly after creating GameScene. I will answer the question with corrected code, in case anyone would later want to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It works with initializing it like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var bg1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "lightSky")
    var bg2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "lightSky")

    var setup: Setup!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.size = view.bounds.size
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -1.0)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        setup = Setup(scene: self)

        setup.setupBackground(bg1, bg2: bg2)
    }
}
```